# Memory type (WB vs USWC) of memory mapped files on x86

Tags: memory, x86, operating-system, cpu-architecture, memory-mapped-files

Different kinds of “memory blocks” can be bound to some range of the virtual address space of a process. Here, I consider coherent persistently mapped video memory and memory mapped files.

I understand that when VRAM is mapped using an API like OpenGL or Vulkan, the returned address range isn’t a “real” piece of memory, but rather a “proxy” that forwards any writes and reads to the GPU (though it likely does some caching in hardware to increase performance, just like in buffer I/O). I heard that this type of “memory” is called USWC - Uncacheable *(not backed by system RAM)* Speculative *(using heuristics)* Write Combining *(buffered I/O)*.

This means that mapped VRAM is fundamentally different from “normal” WB - Write Back Cacheable *(having a place, RAM, to swap to from cache)* - memory. For this reason, using non-temporal instructions like `_mm_stream_si128` or `_mm_stream_load_si128` for memory transfer with VRAM [has a possible performance advantage over regular loads and stores](https://web.archive.org/web/20120918010837/http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/increasing-memory-throughput-with-intel-streaming-simd-extensions-4-intel-sse4-streaming-load/). The CPU knows that there is no point to place a USWC cache line in cache because it isn’t backed by any real memory (apart from VRAM itself).

My question concerns memory mapped files. Are they also USWC memory? If they are, using non-temporal instructions, while working with them, could have a performance advantage. I know that the only way to know is to benchmark, but I am not asking about actual performance numbers, but about the underlying memory structure implementation. On the one hand, it would seem probable that memory mapped files are USWC because, just like VRAM, they are backed only by a “distant” memory. On the other hand, I read that this mapping is usually implemented in the OS by handling page fault interrupts - when a page of a file is missing, the OS pages it in, while when a page is paged out, it is swapped into the file on disk.

How does it work in reality (Windows, Linux, x86_64)?

Comment: Windows only - you have to dig into the driver docs a bit to find this but all file reads and writes are memory mapped IO right at the bottom level of the API stack.  ie the OS  uses the VM paging mechanism to read and write files.

Comment: Memory-mapped regular files are WB cacheable in all mainstream OSes, and it's actually hard to allocate anything else (except by memory-mapping a device file for video RAM).  It's just a software trick unless you have Optane or other NV-DIMM memory-mapped persistent storage, and you use `MAP_SHARED_VALIDATE | MAP_SYNC`.

Comment: The USWC memory type (aka WC in Intel's manuals) is indeed uncacheable, but that means not cacheable *inside the CPU* by L1/L2/L3 cache.  This memory type can be applied to any page, including one backed by normal DRAM rather than PCIe device memory such as video RAM.  No memory-type could make the CPU copy data from VRAM to "system memory" (DRAM) as part of executing a load instruction from video RAM; if you want that you need a load instruction (from VRAM) and a store instruction (to DRAM).

Comment: Fun fact: You can set up WP (write-protect) or WT (write-through) mappings of PCIe device-memory regions, allowing repeated loads of the same address to hit in the CPUs cache.  (But you have to manually invalidate the CPU cache after telling the device to do something that will make it  changed the contents of that memory.)

Comment: This question is too broad and almost all the premises in it are wrong, making it hard to give a complete and correct answer. I'd brush up on how caching works, then move to the type of caching available to x86, then learn about mmapped files, and finally about WC framebuffers.

Comment: "On the other hand, I read that this mapping is usually implemented in the OS by handling page fault interrupts - when a page of a file is missing, the OS pages it in, while when a page is paged out, it is swapped into the file on disk."  This is correct.  The mapped file isn't "backed by distant memory" - it's ordinary memory, and the "backing" by the disk (which is not memory!) is a software feature, not hardware.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the OpenGL api is implemented in a user mode library provided by hardware vendors of GPUs unless the card is open like most Intel/AMD integrated cards and you're using an open source OS. The OpenGL library makes calls in the virtual file reprensenting the GPU but that file is associated with the GPU driver by its file operations. When the GPU driver is registered, the driver's init() function calls a kernel function to associate that virtual file with the driver. It also tells the OS which function to call for each file operation that it wants to implement.

Comment: When you call that file operation from user mode (the OpenGL library), it calls the function registered by the driver instead of the typical hard-disk driver. That function is loaded in kernel mode pages so it can read/write PCI registers and tell the GPU to do something using its PCI interface. Something like reading some memory region and loading that in GPU memory or drawing something on the screen. That's more or less how it works. For GPUs in frambuffer modes, it is most likely exactly the same but you'll use the write operation and set the graphics mode using ioctl().

Comment: Most cards today, probably only ioctl() because RAM framebuffers are slow and you don't need them.